# Place KQL results into an indexable array

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

The problem is simple but the soution is not as straight forward.

I have a KQL query for extracting discinct values from a column

```sql
let Actions = EventLogs
| distinct DeviceVendor
| summarize action = make_list(Action);
```

Using the above it does create succesfully an array with distinct values of `Action` but the array is not indexable, meaning I cannot access its values with `Actions[0]` in later queries.

Sample results:

```
>  ["Action_1","Action_2","Action_3","Action_4"]
```

The aim of the query is to get a sample of results per `Action` category.

e.g.

```sql
EventLogs
| where Action == Actions[0]
| take 5

EventLogs
| where Action == Actions[1]
| take 5
```

There might be a better way of doing this or at least figuring out a way to make the `Actions` array accessible via index values.

Comment: Could you share the sample data for better understanding

Comment: @Aswin Done, added to the description

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the [`toscalar()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/toscalar-function).

for example:

```
let EventLogs = datatable(Action: string)
[
    "Action1",
    "Action2",
    "Action3",
]
;
let Actions = toscalar(
    EventLogs
    | summarize action = make_list(Action)
);
EventLogs
| where Action == Actions[0]
```